# Gorm Golang fetching a collection and its relationships

Tags: orm, go, go-gorm

I recently started using Golang and decided to give GORM a try as an ORM.
It works pretty well on most things, but as most ORMs are sometimes it's limited. Luckily it ties very well into database/sql so I can do custom queries easily.

I'm wondering if there is any other way to do this in gorm:
I have a struct Companies, Companies have one to many relationships w/ emails, addresses, and phones.  I use the following code in gorm to pull a list of companies and their corresponding info.   I use gorm's Preload function.

```
db.DBAccess.
    Model(&companies).
    Count(&dbInfo.Count).
    Order("companies.id asc").
    Offset(offset).
    Limit(length).
    Preload("Addresses").
    Preload("Phones").
    Preload("Emails").
    Find(&companies)
```

This works perfectly fine. However I feel like there is another way to accomplish this without the Preload function. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have in mind?
I general you could implement a query callback, but i don't think that worth the effort. 
Automatic Lazy loading is not possible, since there is no interception mechanism on the structs fields.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the models? I'd kind of expect it to load those up without an explicit call to `Preload` so long as the relation is specified correctly. If not some option should be added to the package like `CascadingRead` that causes a recursive instantiation rather than returning me an object with empty arrays that should hold the many items my current object has foreign key relations with.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the related entities later (only when/if needed), using [DB.Related](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Related) as shown in [the documentation](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#has-many) :

```
// User has many emails
db.Model(&user).Related(&emails)
//// SELECT * FROM emails WHERE user_id = 111;
// user_id is the foreign key, 111 is user's primary key's value

// Specify the foreign key
db.Model(&user).Related(&emails, "ProfileId")
//// SELECT * FROM emails WHERE profile_id = 111;
// profile_id is the foreign key, 111 is user's primary key's value
```

I do not see another way in the documentation.